Data virtualization: "Specified method is not supported" while notifying a GridView of an update
I'm want to build a random-access virtual data source, which is getting its data from an async source. Right now, I'm just trying to make the most basic proof-of-principle: I'm trying to read data from a file and display it in a DataGrid (ultimately, it's DataGrid behaviour that I will want), and I'm trying to build a virtualised collection for it.  Too much code to reproduce even this minimum working example, (and this code is far from production standard - I've been hacking it about to try to expose the problem) but main features are as follows.
In xaml, I specify a DataGrid like this:
<controls:DataGrid controls:DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="HexDump" ItemsSource="{Binding DataRows, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" DataFetchSize="32">
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Addr" Binding="{Binding startAdr, Converter={StaticResource x4Converter}}"/>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Bytes" Binding="{Binding data, Converter={StaticResource x2Converter}}"/>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Chars" Binding="{Binding data, Converter={StaticResource cConverter}}"/>
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>

DataRows is an example of a BufferRandomAccessVirtualiser, which is defined (in part) like this:
public class BufferRandomAccessVirtualiser : IList, INotifyCollectionChanged 
{

    //INotifyCollectionChanged impl

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    // IList impl

    Dictionary <int, BufferedBlock> tempBlocks = new Dictionary<int, BufferedBlock> ();

    public BufferedBlock this[int index] {
        get {
            if (index >= Count) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            if (tempBlocks.ContainsKey(index)) {
                Debug.Write(index); Debug.Write("& ");
                return tempBlocks[index]; 
            }

            Debug.Write(index); Debug.Write("? ");
            var oldItem = tempBlocks[index] = new BufferedBlock(); // placeholder
            loadRowsTask.ContinueWith(rowsResult => { 
                var row = index % rowsPerPage;
                var newItem = new BufferedBlock (rowsResult [row]);
                
                Debug.Write(index); Debug.Write("<");
                tempBlocks[index] = newItem;
                CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, newItem, oldItem, index));
                Debug.Write("> ");
            });
            return tempBlocks[index];
        } 
        set => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // other parts of IList impl - just boilerplate really
}

The idea is: when the DataGrid first asks for a value, there's nothing cached in rows, so I provide an empty BufferedBlock, and begin the process of loading up the correct value.  When the value is ready, I call CollectionChanged to let the DataGrid know.  During that time, if any further requests for that value arrive, I provide a copy of the original value - afterwards, I provide the 'correct' value.
Broadly, this works.  I've found that I need to be absolutely precise about the values in the NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace call - oldItem has to match exacly what's already known to the DataGrid, and newIem has to match precisely the value returned by the next call to the indexer (more on that in a moment).  But I've found two very odd things.  Firstly, something calls the zeroth value repeatedly as the process starts up.  I see this in the debug output (when there's e.g. five values in the collection):
0? 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1? 2? 3? 4? 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0&  ...

and at least one of these comes from the DataGrid calling IList's enumerator.
The other thing, which has me stumped, is that, during the NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace call, the DataGrid calls into the indexer, checks the result matches newItem, and then throws a System.NotSupportedException:
'Specified method is not supported'.  I have no idea which method is not supported (the stack is deep in native code by this time), but I know that when I remove all the columns from the XAML the problem still happens, so it's not my column bindings.  Here's what it looks like when there's only one row of data available:
0? 0& 0& 0& 0& 0<0& Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid.dll Specified method is not supported.

Incidentally, if tempBlocks is already populated, and there's no need to notify an update, the convertors work properly and the Gridview displays the contents correctly.  I'm satisfied that's not where the problem lies.
Does anybody have any idea what the method is that the Gridview is trying to reach?  Have I left something out of the Xaml?  Has anybody seen anything like this before?  (And, for bonus points: what's all that initialisation doing?  And why does the DataGrid need to call the indexer even when I've told it what the new value is?)

It's a DataGrid and not a DataView (which is the view for the ListView). If you are fetching the actual child items from an asynchronous service you should consider to let your collection implement IAsyncEnumerable<T>.  And because it's obviously read-only it should also implement IReadOnlyList<T>. You must also check if the index is < 0. It should be faster if the underlying pool is an array instead of a table structure where the key is the index of the value. Because you expect BufferedBlock to act as a binding source, it should implement INotifyPropertyChanged to avoid leaks.

From a performance perspective it makes more sense to update the original BufferedBlock instead of replacing it. When you assign your collection to an ItemsControl.ItemsSource property then the ItemsSource will immediately enumerate the collection in order to generate the first item containers. Because you defer returning a valid item and you finally raise the CollectionChanged event the ItemsSource has to read from your collection again. That's what you see in your debug output.

The exception is obviously thrown by the DataGrid. It must be in context with your indexer. I'm not sure what loadRowsTask is but calling async code from a property is prone for all kinds of problems. You may want to use background threads instead. I believe this may already solve your problem. It would be really useful to see what your converters are doing. Also note that it looks like CollectionChanged is potentially raised on a background thread as it is raised from a task continuation. Ensure to raise it on the caller's context when you introduce new thread contexts (unexpectedly).

Maybe fixing your async property code and the event context will already fix your issue.

It really makes sense to create a minimal reproducible example so that we can review your code properly. There is a lot of missing context in your current post.

@BionicCode Lots to reply to...
DataGrid not DataView - quie right: brain fade from days chasing almost-identical names!
IAsyncEnumerable - I thought that's not the right way to virtualise a collection for a DataGrid.  I'm trying to follow the (very ambiguous) advice put out by MS and others.
IReadOnlyList: I'll get to that.  I don't believe it's the source of my problem, and it's not part of the eventual use case.
INotifyPropertyChanged: Why does it need this?  Can you direct me to some doucmentation, pls?  I'm not changing the values in the BufferedBlock (that's immutable).

Performance: In this example - just a test strap - I'm not interested in performance.  Best performance is not to store the intermediates at all!  I've got the blocks that have been read from the files.  I've got enough there to create the BufferedBlocks representing each row.  My expectation is that I can abandon both the BufferedBlocks and the file data, and allow the DataGrid to ask me when it needs a refresh.  But that, too, is not the source of my problem.

Interesting comment about the thread.  I can confirm that the exception appears on "MainThread", so I'm unconvinced that this is the source of the malfunction I'm seeing, but I will check it out when I'm back at work tomorrow.  But if this is an issue: I'm surprised.  Isn't the whole point about virtualised data sources that they will refresh asynchronously, on who-knows-what thread?  Isn't the processing behind NotifyCollectionChanges supposed to handle this?

IAsyncEnumerable: Makes sense if you want to enumerate the custom collection e.g. in a foreach. You probably want to realize items (asynchronously) while enumerating the collection. Virtualizing a collection means that not all items are realized immediately. Instead, your collection would already return the final count. You realize the virtual items on read access (e.g. in pages or item-by-item). Read access can be the indexer or the enumerator. Your collection should support both access variants. So you should provide a properly realizing Enumerator and AsyncEnumerator.

IReadOnlyList: I was referring to your read-only indexer. It would just be clean to officially identify your collection as read-only by implementing that interface. I don't expect it to be the source of the problem. This was just my feedback after reviewing your code.

INotifyPropertyChanged: It's a common issue. The binding engine will use the PropertyDescriptor to observe the source object for property changes. This will create a static reference which will make the source object become a GC root (a memory leak). The binding engine can avoid this static reference when the source implements INotifyPropertyChanged or exposes the properties as dependency properties. Dependencies are the preferred binding source as they eliminate the need to use reflection in order to resolve the binding path. This makes dependency properties the fastest option.

Just goolge INotifyPropertyChanged + memory leak. I think JetBrains has a good explanation for this. The binding engine will always listen to property change events, even when you don't intend to change property values - the engine does not know this. This is not relevant if the binding is OneTime or OneWayToSource.

Performance: As mentioned before, I would get the final count of items and then realize them in pages. I was just referring to your implementation that chose to create "placeholder" items. But maybe I got your implementation wrong (there is some missing context). However, depending on the expected size of the collection and the kind of items it really makes sense to reuse created BufferedBlock instances to reduce the memory consumption and ease pressure on the GC.

"Isn't the whole point about virtualised data sources that they will refresh asynchronously, on who-knows-what thread? Isn't the processing behind NotifyCollectionChanges supposed to handle this?" - Data virtualization and asynchronicity are two different totally unrelated things. You can virtualize data synchronously, of course. And because a data binding can only target a DependencyObject, which is a DispatcherObject, bindings are thread affine.

While virtualization/realization could technically operate on any thread context, the final step to return the item to the binding engine must take place on the dispatcher thread. INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event handlers are automatically executed on the dispatcher thread, marshalled by the binding engine. However, this is not the case for the INotifyCollectionChanged event. In general, the client of the collection is responsible to marshall the event back to the correct thread.

But in your case, you are switching to a new thread context internally, which can't be expected by the client of your collection. I recommend capturing the current SynchronizationContext from the constructor to post the CollectionChanged event back to the original context. The client then, as usual, has to take care of the original context e.g., by calling BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization on the dispatcher thread.

In regards of the threading  issue: because properties can't be async you can't await your task. This will likely result that the indexer returns prematurely. In your case the DataGrid will see the virtual tempBlocks[index] value. This may or may not cause the DataGrid to throw -  we can only speculate as you have not provided enough context for a code review. What supports my assumption is that the Debug.Write("> "); never appear to print to the console. Based on the output OnCollectionChanged is properly called which causes the DataGrid to reference the indexer again (prints 0&).

The code never returns to the indexer context to continue the execution of the part after the call to OnCollectionChanged. That's why I believe that the exception is thrown because the DataGrid operates in the wrong context. It entered that context when the CollectionChanged callback was invoked on your new thread context.

Maybe now you get my idea and why I suggested raising the event on the original SynchronizationContext. From what I can see at this point, which is not much, I would say that fixing your realization algorithm, especially the way you utilize tasks and threads, will also fix the exception.

After some additional work (and with hints from BionicCode - thank you!) I've tracked down the problem.  The exception was being generated inside Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGridDataConnection.cs, in NotifyingDataSource_CollectionChanged, at line 926.  See, where it says:
case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
    throw new NotSupportedException();

So, it's not working because whoever wrote the control explicitly prevented it! (I think this is UWP-only - I know other people have got this working just fine in 'conventional' WPF.)   I tried Removeing and then Adding the item, but (apart from creating all kinds of race problems with overlapping updates) it didn't work because every addition and deletion re-numbered and refreshed the existing items, and it enumerated the whole collection.  That completely undermined the data virtualisation.
I really wanted my BufferedBlocks to be immutable (and, that being so, I couldn't understand why BionicCode was recommending using INotifyPropertyChanged). Now I get it: I  stopped trying to Update the collection, and instead I updated just the data in the BufferedBlocks, and it worked!
So, I'm posting this answer in some detail because, after having wasted a week chasing down what I can only regard as a malfunction born of gross idleness inside Microsoft's library, compounded by dud documentation,  I hope this helps somebody else on the same path.
